# Is "Positive manner" a countable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> Developing mental strength is about improving your ability to regulate your emotions, manage your thoughts, and behave in a positive manner, despite your circumstances.

Is "positive manner" a countable noun? Shouldn't it be just "positive manner" or "positive manners" instead?

Comment: 'In a positive manner' is the idiom, the expression that gets used. I'm convinced that trying to analyse fixed phrases becomes unhelpful at some point. If you need a plural, you're probably better going with 'in positive ways'.

Answer (score 0):

Manner (positive is just an adjective there) is an uncountable noun, and so, its meaning is different when it becomes plural.

**uncountable**

a way of doing, being done, or happening; mode of action, occurrence, etc.

I don't like the *manner* in which he complained.

**countable**=

1. the prevailing customs, ways of living, and habits of a people, class, period, etc.

   The novels of Jane Austen are concerned with the *manners* of her time.
2. ways of behaving with reference to polite standards; social comportment:

   That child has good *manners*.

Comment: Your first example is countable. It's identifying a particular manner. Mass nouns can take "much": "How much rice would you like?"